# Need to get the sum of every other column in matrix

Tags: arrays, for-loop, matrix

Need help in getting the sum of every other Column. The method that I need help with is SumofC method (or the last method). Therefore if I input a 3x3 column it will look like this:

> ```
> 1 2 3 
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
> ```
>
> the sum of every other column would = 30
>   hence 1+4+7 = 12 (1st column), 3+6+9 = 18(3rd column) add the 1st column and 3nd columns to get 30. I already have the sum of every column, what I need is to the get sum of every other column. Therefore every odd columns and add it all together to get one whole number.

```
  public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int n = S.nextInt();

        int [][] matrix = new int [n][n];

        int k = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }
        PrintMatrix(matrix);
        sumofC(matrix);
    }
    public static void PrintMatrix(int [][] matrix)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    //Sum of every Column starting at the 1st.
    public static void sumofC(int [][] num)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++)
            {
                sum += num[j][i];

            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question? It seems like you define and answer your own problem. Also, you don't HAVE to make every method public static void. In fact, I don't see why you'd do that.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner and just kind of copy what my teacher does.

Comment: It's ok, nobody begins as an expert.

Comment: It seems like I did but my program display the sum of all the columns. What I need to do is sum every other column, so every odd column. and then display the sum total of adding all the odd columns together. So therefore if i make a 3x3 matrix it would give me a total sum of 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a sum of every odd column. That is 1st, 3rd, 5th etc generally. In a programming language you start one less, so it's 0, 2, 4 etc. In your `sumofC` method's first loop, you increase `i` by one each time. You just need to change it to be increased by two and you're done. That is, `i+=2`, and you're done.
To add the sum of all columns, just use another variable, `sumOfAllCols` for example, and do `sumOfAllCols += sum;` before printing the `sum` variable.

Comment: How would i get rid of the 12 in the output? It's giving me this output: Enter a number: 3/n 12/n   30/n

Comment: @IDK I can't reply in my sleep :p Glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `sumofC` method, instead of doing `i++` in `for` statement, you can write `i+=2` to skip every alternate columns.

However, if the numbers in the matrix will always contain number in pattern as in your code, then you can calculate the answer in `O(1)` time complexity. As a hint, you can use formula for sum of numbers in **Arithmetic Progression**

Comment: How would you add the total of column 1 and column 3? etc... Btw thanks for the help.

Comment: @IDK To do that, with your naive approach, you just have to put `System.out.println(sum);` outside the outer for loop.
To print this total sum without even looping (ie in constant time), you can use formula for sum of A.P. series. Number in each column is an A.P., sum of numbers in each column is again an A.P. there is a direct formula for sum of numbers in A.P. The formula is: (n/2)*(2*a+(n-1)*d).
Sum of first column is (n/2)*(2+(n-1)*n), for third column, it is (n/2)*(6+(n-1)*n) and so on. These sums are again in A.P. 
So, total sum is:
`((ceil(n/2))/2)*(n*(2+(n-1)*n)+(ceil(n/2)*2*n))`